# vs2019 'SharpDX.Toolkit.Compiler' could not be found after Nuget package update

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I have an old WPF/HelixToolkit/SharpDX project from 2016 that I started working with.  I was having some viewport issues and thought they might be cured by updating HelixToolkit & SharpDX packages.  Unfortunately, after the updates my project will no longer compile.

I tried Build->Clean and Rebuild All, but no joy.  Still getting these errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "SharpDX.Toolkit.EffectCompilerTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly \SharpDX.Toolkit.CompilerTask.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\SharpDX.Toolkit.CompilerTask.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   MyWPFMagViewer2 

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The referenced component 'SharpDX.Toolkit.Compiler' could not be found. MyWPFMagViewer2
```

I'm really hoping it's something simple, but I don't have a clue what it might be. Can anyone help?

TIA,

Frank

Answer (score 0):

I never found an answer to this problem, but I was able to work around it by re-cloning my project from GitHub, and *not* updating SharpDX

Frank